# Need help with creating a custom material node with python

Tags: python, materials, node-editor, pynodes

I'm trying to make a custom node in python, and I've been able to make the input and output sockets, but I have no idea how to connect the input float values to the output float values. I've already tried learning parts of the Blender API in order to figure out how to do this, but I've made no progress. How do I connect the inputs to the outputs, or even set an output value at all?

Comment: Could you expand your question by telling which render engine do you want to use, what is the main function of the node and which classes are you using from the API?

Comment: Also, it would help if you could share your existing code so that others can build upon it.

Comment: I'm using cycles and the main functions of the node are the random.seed() and var = random.random function. The code's kinda bad and messy so I dunno how useful sharing it would be.